# How to position two divs one on each other at the bottom of parent?

Tags: css

[In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gd5pqky7/) I was able put two divs on each other at the bottom of their parent, but only because I knew the height of last div. The first one was moved a bit to the top. What if the height of `#second` is dynamic? How can we make them sit on each other **at the bottom of parent** with dynamic heights? Is it even possible with css? Please do not post JavaScript or jQuery versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Flexbox`. With `justify-content: flex-end` and you can move content to end of **parent** element, so if you want to position some other child element on top of parent you can use `margin-bottom: auto`. This applies if you set `flex-direction: column` on parent.

```css
.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.main {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  <div class="box">One</div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati vel molestiae dolores, ad, nulla harum tenetur minima aperiam debitis id atque fugit, modi error et magni eius repellendus saepe. Vero?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like kind of css hack. Never seen such css before and I like it. Thanks for the lesson and your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not hack, you can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap both of them in a div and set position absolute style for that div rather than applying them individually..

working [Fiddle][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gd5pqky7/
```

Comment: Just wondering why I didnt thought about that. Must be friday... But I prefer Nenad Vracar's hacky answer `:>` Thanks for help!

Comment: @ksno Most Welcome :)